# Scala Play framework Forms, type not automatically inferred for a tuple parameter

Tags: scala, types, playframework

I'm learning to use forms in Play Framework and I have the following problem. I have a case class like this:

```
case class Part(id:          Option[Int],
                description: String,
                created:     DateTime)
```

and I'm trying to retrieve/populate it from/to a Play Form defined like this:

```
val addPartForm = Form(
    mapping(
        "description" -> text
    )(tp => Part.apply(id = None, description = tp._1, created = new DateTime()))
     (pt => (pt.description)))
```

so basically I'm trying to provide a custom mapping functions as the usual Part.apply and Part.unapply versions are not an exact match/map. When I try to compile this code it gives an error on the `tp` parameter saying `missing parameter type`. Why the type for `tp` can't be inferred automatically? If I provide the type for `tp` explicitly it does compile. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try describing the resulting tuple as follows:

```
val addPartForm = Form(
   mapping(
      "description" -> text
   )((description) => Part(id = None, description = description, created = new DateTime()))
   (part => Some(part.description))
)
```

Comment: I've realized that the compiler can't really infer the size of the tuple in this case that's why it is asking for the type.